# Return usage in Java recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Example {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        printTriangle(4);

    }

     static void printLine(int width){
            for (int i = 0; i< width; i ++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

     static void printTriangle(int height){
            if (height <= 0){
                return;
            }

            printTriangle(height-1);
            printLine(height);
        }   
}
```

In method `printTraingle()` how does argument for `printLine(height)` increments each time after calling .First `height` gets decremented to 1 and then it reincrement to 4 . How is this possible

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but I suspect that if you step through the code in the debugger it'll help you understand. You might also want to add `System.out.println` lines of "Calling `printTriangle`" and "Call finished..." with the height...

Comment: And if you dont have a debugger at hand ... seriously, grep a sheet of paper and a pen. And then "run" the program manually. Write down the numbers, "execute" each step, and "update" the numbers. That is the best way in the end to figure what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answers . Both helped me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others told you in the comments above, you can do different things to figure it out before posting a question.

But a hint for you that answers your question is that the recursion starts with this line:

```
printTriangle(height-1);
```

And only once the recursion is done, does this line get executed:

```
printLine(height);
```

Hope this gives you a hint.